# How do you create a translator in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

What I am trying to do is make a program react with words I define to translate it into a language, or in my case, letters.

This would be an example of what I want:

I type in "Woof" per say. I want it to be able to understand what I say when I type woof, and print a letter with it.

So let's say "Woof" is the letter "A"
And let's say "Arf bark" is the letter "B"

I've had no luck finding how to be able to input say "Woof arf bark" and get it to print "AB"

My end goal is to be able to translate words with my own little translator using my own defined language by simply inputing words.

What I'm looking for in a response is simply an example of inputing a defined word and receiving a letter or something in response.

Long story-short; I am basically looking for a translator

---

**Edit:** Imagine Google Translate, you type in a word or a series of letters or whatever be the case, and it becomes translated.
I'm looking for it to be able to UNDERSTAND INPUT. So If I copy and paste the made up language, the IDE should be able to give me a translation of it.

**Better Example:** Let's say H is defined as "8" because it is the 8th letter in the alphabet, and A is defined as "1" due to being the first letter in the alphabet.
How do I write a program that allows me to input "8181" and have it translated to say "Haha"

Comment: There are entire books devoted to how you parse an input text into a form suitable for translation, let alone how to translate one stream of words into another (it's almost never as simple as just replacing each word with a unique equivalent from some dictionary). This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @chepner I disagree only because OP states that he want to define the language. if that is the case, and he controls the encoding and decoding then he is simply asking for a dictionary.

Comment: Essentially a dictionary that I can input to translate.

Imagine google translate, except in Python.

Comment: That's what I though, until I saw his comment on the answer. For starters, how do you know how to break up "woof arf bark"? Is it one three-word token? Three one-word tokens? One of two possible sets of two tokens? And that's just for a single two-"word" language.

Comment: "Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana". You can't translate that using simple dictionary look-ups.

Comment: Let's say each term/word is separated by a comma.
So if I were to type per say "woof, arf bark," It would be two different words/terms to translate

Comment: Then that fundamentally changes your question and you should update your question to reflect it @chepner is right about the token size without the commas. with them you are I believe one csv parser and a for loop away from using a dictionary to perform the type of translation you are looking for.

Comment: Updated. The edit should make it a little easier to understand

Comment: Your update doesn't make the situation any better for 2 reasons. 1st you didn't mention delimiters. Without the ability to start off knowing how the tokens are being presented to your translator, the problem will quickly become computationally prohibitive. 2nd your desire to obtain understanding is one that is being chased by many really smart people spending 40 hours a week programming NLP algorithms. You're not going to get understanding in your program with a few lines of code.

Comment: Your second example is a cipher that could literally be written as `"".join(chr(ord('A') + int(val) - 1) for val in "8181")`. Also, as someone who knows multiple languages, Google Translate makes a great dictionary but a horrible translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Semicolons and Duct Tap's* answer provides a neat way to do this, provided that you can filter the input however you want to.

Using only his suggestion, however, you would not be able to parse "Woof arf bark": This would get split into `["Woof","arf","bark"]`. You would, however, be able to parse "Woof, arf bark".

That might be enough for you. If not, read on...

**Handling complicated input**

If you want to separate things using a character that might be in one of your words, as in your example (woof arf bark) things get a bit more complicated.
Based on that example, it might be worth looking into [regular expressions.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

These can give you a better way to parse input, if you want to be able to recognize everywhere in your string that matches a word you need to output.

This will let you make things look simple to the user, but can also slow things down if you have a long string and a complicated expression to match. If you choose this path, you could use re.findall() to separate your text.

**An example**

Using a dictionary, lets say you have:

```
words = {"woof":A,"arf bark":B}
input = "woof,arf bark"
inputList = input.split(',')
for word in inputList:
    print words[word]
```

This example does not use a regular expression (or regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
A = raw_input("Enter a word to be transcribed to A")
#user types "Woof"
check = raw_input("Enter your secret code")
if check == A:
    print "A"
    #will print out "A"
```

Comment: How would I go amongst making words? It works fine with just one term/letter.

Thanks for the help BTW!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking for a dictionary.

here is how to use them in Python:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

and a little code that demonstrates their use lifted from the page:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dict = {'Name': 'Zara', 'Age': 7, 'Class': 'First', 'your word': 'translated word'};

print "dict['Name']: ", dict['Name']
print "dict['Age']: ", dict['Age']
print "dict['your word']: ", dict['your word'] #dict['your name'] will return 'translated word'
```

just add all your fake language into dictionary keys and what you want the words translated to in the keys' value locations.

you can then take a string and split it on a delimiter of your choice (you suggest using a comma in your comments) and then send the values you get in the split list to the dictionary to translate the string.

Answer (score -2):

With the translate module:

```
from translate import Translator
languageName=input('Enter language name:')
transalat=input('What to transalate?:')
translator = Translator(to_lang=languageName)
translation = translator.translate(transalat)
print(translation)
```